# Azure Firewall Inbound traffic Logs

Tags: azure, vpn, firewall

I am unable to view any inbound traffic logs in Azure Firewall. I am trying to view in Log Analytics and can see only the outbound traffic logs which are from Azure. Is there any settings to be enabled to view the traffic?

I even tried running the below query to see any traffic coming from my machine.

AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceType == "AZUREFIREWALLS"
and msg_s contains "request from 192.168.6.12"
and msg_s contains "Allow"

Answer (score 0):

Before Writing query, make sure you have already **enabled** diagnostic log to be sent to Log Analytics.

- If you have more than one Azure Firewall in your subscription and you
  want to retrieve log from one of them:

```html
AzureDiagnostics 
| where Category == "AzureFirewallNetworkRule" 
    and Resource  == "SELECTEDFIREWALLNAME"
```

(or)

```
let deny_log = 
    AzureDiagnostics
    | where Category == "AzureFirewallApplicationRule"
        and msg_s contains "Deny";
deny_log
| summarize count() by msg_s
```

### Can select in-built queries from already available query packs like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

You may refer  [this](https://azsec.azurewebsites.net/2018/07/23/azure-firewall-monitoring-101/) for few Other Azure Firewall Log Query samples

```
(Or)
```

You may try one of the most effective ways to [view and analyze Azure Firewall logs by using Workbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/firewall-workbook) that allow you to combine text, Log Analytics query, Azure metrics and parameters, thus conseasing interactive and easily searchable reports.

> Azure Firewall Workbook allows you to filter your firewalls and
> resource groups, and dynamically filter per category with easy to read
> data sets when investigating an issue in your logs.

See how to **monitor and analyze Azure Firewall logs using workbooks** [here](https://francescomolfese.it/en/2020/12/azure-networking-come-monitorare-ed-analizzare-i-log-di-azure-firewall/)

References:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/firewall-diagnostics
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/logs-and-metrics

Comment: I am able to see all the outbound logs in log analytics which means my diagnostic has been enabled. Here when I try to connect RDP to a VM from 192.168.6.12, that log is not showing. When I run the above command, there are no results

Answer (score 0):

Just went through this. I have a vWan, and there are settings on the vHub -> Routing Intent and Routing Policies page that determine where traffic from the vpn routes to. By default, it does not go to the Azure Firewall, so it's free to go wherever it wants. This can be preferabe because there is already a firewall on the other end of the vpn connection determining what can go where. But if you want the Azure firewall to filter and inspect the vpn traffic you can flip the setting and get that.